# xml namespaces in xsl transform - ignore blank?

Tags: templates, xslt

I'm new to xsl and am trying to write a template to transform xml to html.

I have an xml document that begins

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <data xmlns:autn="http://schemas.com/aci/" 
 xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/">
  <name>Bob</name>
```

and my xsl template begins

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      
xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/"> 
...
<body>
<p>user name:</p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="data/name"/></p>
```

The problem is, if I do
    
I don't get anything back for the value-of select.

If I do 
    
I get 'Bob' but I lose all my html.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the default namespace of the XML document:

```
xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/"
```

Add it to the XSLT as well:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:mynamespace="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"      
  xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/">
```

And use that namespace in the `xsl:value-of`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="mynamespace:data/mynamespace:name" />
```